# Simple regex doesn't work in Chrome extension (Popup.js)

Tags: regex, google-chrome

I have an issue that is driving me nuts. All other regex' are working, but they "stop" working if it includes a letter.

The string is as following:

```
مسلسل The Outsider 2020 الموسم الاول الحلقة 8 مترجمة
```

I want to get the number "8". The text can be understood as "Series x Season y Episode NUMBER". I'm trying to get the number using the following regex:

```
/(?<=.*الحلقة.*)[0-9]+(?=.*)/g
```

It's working fine when applying it here https://regexr.com/ OR on the console. I'm implementing it in the Popup.js file.

The following regex is working fine without issues

```
/(?<=title=")(.*?)(?=")/
```

My JS code to get the regex:

```
        let episodeNumber = item.match(/(?<=title=")(.*?)(?=")/)[0];
        console.log("t: " + episodeNumber);
        episodeNumber = episodeNumber.match(/(?<=.*الحلقة.*)[0-9]+(?=.*)/g);
        console.log(episodeNumber);
```

The first log gives me the result (the text above) 
The second log gives null in the console. It's really weird.

If the regex isn't formatted well, please replace "الحلقة" with "Episode". It's in Arabic, that's why it would look weird in the formatting.

Comment: Only few languages support variable length lookbehind. In your first regex the lookbehind is fixed length but variable in second regex.

Comment: Nevertheless, the regex works in the console. I'm using it on Chrome and therefore, Chrome should support it considering that it worked on the console, right?

Comment: I get `8` with the `"مسلسل The Outsider 2020 الموسم الاول الحلقة 8 مترجمة".match(/(?<=الحلقة.*)[0-9]+/g)[0]` code